Crystal Reports for Visual Studio Data Set DataSource Location Problem
I'm using version 13.0.33.4485.  This has only happened lately, so maybe it's a bug or change in the version.
When I'm in design mode for my report, when I try to Set DataSource Location (or Verify Database), I'm now shown the attached screen
I'm just trying to use a .net class as the datasource, I'm not sure why this is coming up now when it never has before.  I'm just trying to add some new fields to my object.  BTW, the program actually sets the datasource at runtime when the report is actually executed.

you need a database like a xml or adataset access db and so on, if your class has no daraset, how can it be a datasource, sldo what os your class?

There are several SQL Server databases defined from the entity framework code-first structures,  I didn't get this screen 6 months ago.  I can see that a dataset might be useful for the preview screen.

BTW, version 13.0.35.4870 still has the problem.

The .net object that is the datasource is generated at runtime.  I'd have to create a program to generate a sample version of the dataset, save it as an XML file, then do it all over again every time I added a field.  Cumbersome to say the least.

you can build the Report once with th xml and crystal can use every datasource that has teh same structure like the dataset

see here where they do the same https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/531776/Entity-Framework-and-Crystal-Reports-Entities-to-D

I rolled back my Crystal Reports for VS to SP 31, and reinstalled VS 2019, and modified my record structure, used Set DataSourceLocation to import the revised record structure.  Then rolled forward to SP 35 again.  Generating the XML from Crystal isn't going to work, because that would have the old record structure, not the changed one.  I'd have to generate the XML from the internal dataset, which is something I'll have to investigate when I have more time.
